# Showing The Error "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC" While export to excel 2013 from C#

Tags: c#, excel, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

While Exporting from C# to Excel 2013, the following Error is showing

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

The following code am using. to export the data  from dataTable to Excel from c#

```
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet objWorkSheet1 = null;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application objExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    {
      Visible = false,
      DisplayAlerts = false,
      ScreenUpdating = false,
      DisplayClipboardWindow = false,

     };
     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks objWorkbooks = objExcel.Workbooks;
     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook objWorkbook = objWorkbooks.Add(Missing.Value);
     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets objSheets = objWorkbook.Worksheets;
     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range objCells;
     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range myCell;
     var iCurrentRow = 10;
     var dt = ds;
     int columnsCount = dt.Columns.Count;
     objWorkSheet1 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)(objSheets[1]);
     objCells = objWorkSheet1.Cells;
     objWorkSheet1.Cells[2, columnsCount - 1] = ReportCaption;
     objWorkSheet1.Cells[2, columnsCount - 1].Font.Size = 15;
     objWorkSheet1.Range[objWorkSheet1.Cells[5, 2], objWorkSheet1.Cells[5, columnsCount - 1]].Merge();
     objWorkSheet1.Cells[5, 2] = "Printed By: " + Common.Utilities.UserName; ;
     objWorkSheet1.Range[objWorkSheet1.Cells[6, 2], objWorkSheet1.Cells[6, columnsCount - 1]].Merge();
     objWorkSheet1.Cells[6, 2] = "Date: " + DateTime.Now;
     objWorkSheet1.Range[objWorkSheet1.Cells[2, 2], objWorkSheet1.Cells[4, columnsCount - 1]].Merge();
     if (name != null)
       if (name.Length > 0)
           objWorkSheet1.Cells[8, 2] = "NAME: " + name;
                       objWorkSheet1.get_Range((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)objWorkSheet1.Cells[2, 2], (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)objWorkSheet1.Cells[4, columnsCount - 1]).Cells.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
                objWorkSheet1.get_Range((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)objWorkSheet1.Cells[2, 2], (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)objWorkSheet1.Cells[4, columnsCount - 1]).Cells.VerticalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;

  for (var h = 0; h < dt.Columns.Count; h++)
  {
     myCell = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)objCells[iCurrentRow, h + 1];
     myCell.Value2 = dt.Columns[h].ColumnName;
   }
   iCurrentRow++;


     for (var r = 0; r < dt.Rows.Count; r++)
       {
         for (var c = 0; c < dt.Columns.Count; c++)
         {
           if (dt.Columns[c].DataType.Name == "String" || dt.Columns[c].DataType.Name == "DateTime")
           {
              myCell = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)objCells[r + iCurrentRow, c + 1];
              myCell.Value2 = "'" + dt.Rows[r][c].ToString().Trim();
           }
           else
           {
             myCell = (Mirosoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)objCells[r + iCurrentRow, c + 1];
             myCell.Value2 = dt.Rows[r][c];
           }
       }
     }
      objWorkSheet1.Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit();
      objWorkSheet1.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
      objWorkbook.SaveAs(savingFileName,   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal,
                    Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive,
                    Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
                    Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
    objWorkbook.Close(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
    objExcel.Quit();
```

The following line shows the above error

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal‌​, 
 Missing.Value, Missing.Value, true, true,
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusiv‌​e,
 false,false, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
```

Comment: thats not even a whole line of code.. what exactly are you doing?

Comment: Ok i will put the whole code

Comment: Have you googled ? a lot of this seems to be saying either 1 cells data is too large, or you are saving to a name in use.  If you view excel when this happens what happens if you do the save manually when the app errors

Comment: Same error Occures with different code i tried

Comment: didnt answer my question

Comment: s i googled. no we cant view the excel .. it is blank with out any fields and , if we skip it will be in catch

Comment: So when it stops with an error excel is blank? then it suggests the error is not in the line you think

Comment: from that line it going to catch., while debugging

Comment: ok but then it shouldnt have a blank work book should it

Comment: no am selecting the sheet1    `objWorkSheet1 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)(objSheets[1]);`

Comment: but you said its blank.. it shouldnt be blank!

Comment: s with out any values..